# Properly adjusting multiple toggle on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have a view page that with the click of the edit button (toggle) the view page changes into an edit mode page.

One the edit button is clicked - it will convert the items into removable items by adding a minus sign to the right. Also a lest of items will appear to the right.

How can i better structure so that when i click on the close btn it will make sure it will default to the initial view page?

here is a start to jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/85m4u/

```
<a class="editButton">Edit</a>
<br>
<div class="listofItems">
    <div style="float:left">
        item 1<br>
        item 2<br>
        item 3<br>
    </div>
    <div class="remove" style="float:right; display:none">
        - <br>
        - <br>
        - <br>    
     </div>
 </div>
<div class="fullItems" style="display:none">
     Test 1<br>
     Test 2<br>
     Test 3<br>
</div>

    <button class="closebtn">close</button>
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $("#editButton").click(function(){
        $(".actions").toggle();
        $(".remove").toggle();
        $("fullItems").toggle();
    })
})
```

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/85m4u/2/

Comment: @RobinvdA somewhat yes but i want to have it so that when the edit button is clicked again it goes back to normal state. And when i click close on normal state it doesn't change to edit mode. Also when i click edit i am supposed to see ' Test 1'... on the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few errors in it

Change your jQuery to this:

```
$(function(){
  $(".editButton, .closebtn").click(function(){
    $(".actions").toggle();
    $(".remove").toggle();
    $(".fullItems").toggle();
  });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/85m4u/3/